# in codeigniter how do I fetch one row in table1 and one row in table2

Tags: codeigniter

Please I am having challenge in this, please I need help
I have two tables

brand

brand_id

---

1
2
3
4
5

pic

brand_id  pic_url

---

1
1
1
2
2
2

```
Controller
$data = array();
$data['brands']=$this->brand_model->getBrandpic();
$this->load->view('brand/index'); // just the header file

model
public function getBrandpic() {
        this->db->order_by("add_date", "desc");
        $query=$this->db->join('brand', 'pic.brand_id = brand.brand_id');
        $query=$this->db->get('pic');
}

view
<?php foreach ($brands as $brand) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $brand->pic_url; ?>" alt="Image" class="img-responsive" style="width:300px; height:200px;">
<?php echo $brand->brand_id; ?>


<?php } ?>
```

This is pulling out all pic_url that belongs to brand_id, I dont want it so; I want just one pic url for a brand_id.
Please how do i go about this.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry the table is not well arranged the figures in the table are supposed to be arranged in the brand_id column of the two tables respectively and they are arranged vertically

Comment: Can you please edit your desired output so I can help you. I'm not sure what do you need thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have a query like "Select 1 from brand where brand_id="somebrandid" " in your model where the data is being returned.

Comment: Thanks, but pls how will the query look like in the model as select 1 means selecting the column name. How do I write it in such a way that it it will limit it to one as you meant to say

Comment: You can do this to add limit "$this->db->limit(10, 20);  " 10 is min and 20 is max.

Comment: That is retrieving only one records from the table from the multitudes. I want all records but the limit should be on the brand_id

Comment: I am not quite understanding your problem.